# Azure IoT Hub Package Update for Windows Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I have a Windows based software written in C# as a `BackgroundWorker` class, communicating with Azure IoT Hub (bascially a remote control/management endpoint).

It runs as a Windows service.

I would like to leverage IoT Hub Device Update, for this Windows agent, using th Package Update method - and have it update the service with the released software.

I can see a [tutorial for Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-ubuntu-agent), but nothing for Windows and only [mention of porting to other platforms](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/blob/main/docs/agent-reference/how-to-modify-the-agent-code.md) - before i start going down a rabbit hole and implementing a [Windows platform layer](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/tree/main/src/platform_layers), looking for any examples/implementations for Windows specifically.

Comment: Already an open issue on GitHub: [Add support for windows packages in ADU](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues/62#issuecomment-840790836)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a PM on the Device Update for IoT Hub team. In general, we intend Device Update for IoT Hub to be our first effort at bringing the kind of powerful update management capabilities that Windows already enjoys to the non-Windows (IoT) world. With a decade-plus of Microsoft investment in Windows update management already, our team's initial focus and investment for the DU offering, then, have been on Linux and RTOS variants for IoT specifically. For that reason, we don’t have a specific plan yet for Windows support in Device Update for IoT Hub.

However, the DU offering is flexible by design such that any devices connected to Azure IoT Hub can be updated by Device Update if the open-source DU Agent that we make available is ported to the OS running on those devices, and if the appropriate handler (installer) for the update type is also available on that device. That is something that could possibly unblock you if you were willing to do the porting work. We definitely hear feedback on the desirability of managing updates for both Windows and non-Windows IoT devices connected to Azure IoT Hub using a single stack and experience, and would be interested in hearing more details about your specific scenario.”

Comment: Thanks Andrew! IoT Hub is actually very useful for management scenarios - we started building Windows app service using service bus but quickly realised we are implementing much of what IoT Hub already does (cloud to machine, request response, jobs etc). I imagine I am not the only one using it for this scenario. I have looked at porting to Windows the C++ functions look OK however not sure how one would tie this into the actual OS itself (calling OS level commands to stop/remove/install/start the service). Pointers in that would be appreciated i may then take a punt.